# Is that possible to use Interactive Push Notifications in ExpoKit?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

Is that possible to use `Interactive Push Notifications` in `ExpoKit`? Or this feature is only available in pure `Expo` now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you will not be able to use Expo’s Interactive push notifications outside of a managed `Expo` project. There are some other alternatives can be used such as [wix/react-native-ntifications](https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications).